# SQL count specific value over multiple columns and rows

Tags: mysql, sql

I feel as if this should be quite easy, but can't seem to find a solution.
Suppose I have the following table:

```
|--------||---||---||---||---||---||---||---|
|Company ||q1 ||q2 ||q3 ||q4 ||q5 ||q6 ||q7 |
|--------||---||---||---||---||---||---||---|
|abc     ||1  ||2  ||1  ||3  ||2  ||2  ||1  |
|abc     ||2  ||2  ||1  ||2  ||3  ||1  ||1  |
|abc     ||1  ||1  ||3  ||3  ||1  ||2  ||2  |
|abc     ||1  ||2  ||1  ||3  ||0  ||1  ||3  |
```

I want to count the number of times '1' appears in the table, so the query should, in this case, result with 12. I tried 'hardcoding' it, like the following query. But that just results in the rows containing a 1, so in this case 4. How do I count the number of times '1' occurs, thus resulting in a count of 12?

```
SELECT COUNT(*) 
FROM table
WHERE Company = 'abc'
AND (
q1 =  '1'
OR q2 =  '1'
OR q3 =  '1'
OR q4 =  '1'
OR q5 =  '1'
OR q6 =  '1'
OR q7 =  '1'
)
```

Comment: `AND  '1' IN (q1,q2,q3,q4,q5,q6,q7)`

Comment: Nope, that results in COUNT 4 as well

Comment: At heart, the reason your approach didn't and cannot work is that `count()` counts rows and so a set of 1s across multiple columns would only be counted a single time.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
SELECT SUM(
    IF(q1 = 1, 1, 0) +
    IF(q2 = 1, 1, 0) +
    IF(q3 = 1, 1, 0) +
    IF(q4 = 1, 1, 0) +
    IF(q5 = 1, 1, 0) +
    IF(q6 = 1, 1, 0) +
    IF(q7 = 1, 1, 0)
)
FROM table
WHERE Company = 'abc'
```

Comment: Ended up using this solution, exactly what I was looking for!

Answer (score 4):

This is very weird assignment but:

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/2e7aa/3

```
SELECT SUM((q1='1')+(q2='1')+(q3='1')+(q4='1')+(q5='1')+(q6='1')+(q7='1')) 
FROM table
WHERE Company = 'abc'
AND '1' IN (q1,q2,q3,q4,q5,q6,q7)
```

Comment: This is the shortest (and clearest) answer, relying on the fact that booleans are actually treated as integers `0` or `1` in MySQL. The addition of `AND '1' IN (q1,q2,q3,q4,q5,q6,q7)` probably makes it the most efficient too.

Answer (score 3):

Not so easy, each column needs to be hard-coded. I'd try something using a `CASE` or `DECODE`.

```
SELECT 
SUM(
CASE WHEN q1 = 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END +
CASE WHEN q2 = 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END +
CASE WHEN q3 = 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END +
CASE WHEN q4 = 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END +
CASE WHEN q5 = 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END +
CASE WHEN q6 = 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END +
CASE WHEN q7 = 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)
FROM table
WHERE Company = 'abc'
```

Using a `SUM` instead of a `COUNT` will allow the `CASE` statement to be `SUM`ed.

Comment: Just personal preference, both query do the same result but using `count` would make it easier for others know what are you trying to do.

Answer (score 3):

Use conditional `COUNT`

```
SELECT COUNT(case when q1 = '1' then 1 end)  + 
       COUNT(case when q2 = '1' then 1 end)  + 
       COUNT(case when q3 = '1' then 1 end)  + 
       COUNT(case when q4 = '1' then 1 end)  + 
       COUNT(case when q5 = '1' then 1 end)  + 
       COUNT(case when q6 = '1' then 1 end)  + 
       COUNT(case when q7 = '1' then 1 end) as ones_total
FROM table
WHERE Company = 'abc'
```

Answer (score 2):

For reasons of efficiency I don't recommend actually using this approach; but for learning purposes here's another way you could have broken down the problem along the lines of the way you were thinking about it.

```
select sum(c) as total_ones
from
    (
    select count(*) c from table where q1 = 1 union all
    select count(*)   from table where q2 = 1 union all
    select count(*)   from table where q3 = 1 union all
    select count(*)   from table where q4 = 1 union all
    select count(*)   from table where q5 = 1 union all
    select count(*)   from table where q6 = 1 union all
    select count(*)   from table where q7 = 1
    ) t
```